# Media capture initializing error

Tags: c#, camera, uwp, media

I have a problem with UWP media capture initilization. My code is below,

```
private async Task StartPreviewAsync()
{
    try
    {
        //set initilize settings
        Settings oneSetting = null;

        using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), sqlpath))
        {
            oneSetting = (from p in conn.Table<Settings>()
                          where p.id == 0
                          select p).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        if (oneSetting.camera != null)
        {
            var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings();
            settings.StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video;
            settings.PhotoCaptureSource = PhotoCaptureSource.VideoPreview;
            var devices = await Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceClass.VideoCapture);

            foreach (var device in devices)
            {
                if ((device.Id).Equals(oneSetting.cameraId))
                {
                    settings.VideoDeviceId = device.Id;
                    break;
                }
            }

            _mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
            await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);

            //MediaCapture m = new MediaCapture();
            //await m.InitializeAsync();

            var focusSettings = new FocusSettings();
            focusSettings.AutoFocusRange = AutoFocusRange.FullRange;
            focusSettings.Mode = FocusMode.Auto;
            focusSettings.WaitForFocus = true;
            focusSettings.DisableDriverFallback = false;

            _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.Configure(focusSettings);
            await _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.ExposureControl.SetAutoAsync(true);

            _mediaCapture.SetPreviewRotation(VideoRotation.Clockwise90Degrees);
            _mediaCapture.SetRecordRotation(VideoRotation.Clockwise90Degrees);

            capturePreview.Source = _mediaCapture;
            await _mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
            _isPreviewing = true;

            _displayRequest.RequestActive();
            DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations.Landscape;
        }
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        // This will be thrown if the user denied access to the camera in privacy settings
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The app was denied access to the camera");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("MediaCapture initialization failed. {0}", ex.Message);
    }
}
```

It returns MediaCapture initialization failed. {0} error. Recently, it runs well. But since this morning it gives the error. Is there anybody who takes the same error?

The full error message is that;

The specified device interface level or feature is not supported on this system.
: Media Capture initialization failed. {0}
The thread 0x1924 has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: What is your error message? Just "MediaCapture initialization failed. {0} error."???

Comment: The full error message is that;

The specified device interface level or feature is not supported on this system.
: Media Capture initialization failed. {0}
The thread 0x1924 has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same issue here.
After many hours of retries and googling i realize that it was related to the windows 10 anniversary update. 
I found the solution here:

https://www.macecraft.com/fix-webcam-issues-windows-10-anniversary-update/

I added the EnableFrameServerMode key in the registry and magically the webcam came back working.

Answer (score 0):

> But since this morning it gives the error.

Did you recently update your device OS? On which device did you meet this problem and what is the OS version?

I personally think this is more like a device problem or drive issue. You can try to restart your device and see if this helps. Or you can start the built-in camera app and check if this official app runs well.

I'm writing this answer here because there are too many details need to be confirmed, please leave a comment here to tell us the detail information about your device and your test result based on my suggestion, so can we keep look into this issue.

Comment: I run it on Windows 10 Pro. Recently some updates have been done. I think, the issue is about these updates. The other cam applications run well on the same machine. I could not find any solution. The problem is not about camera device or drivers. Because I tried two different cam. Is there someone else who encounters same issue?

Comment: @mücahitaltıntaş, no, I didn't get such issue report for now, what is your OS version? OS build 14393? Can you please try to run the official [Basic camera app sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraStarterKit) on your device? Is that possible that you share your demo with us?

Comment: Of course, I tried  Basic camera app sample. But, it gave the same error. My Os build is 14393 and  .Net framework version is 4.6.01586. Sory, I couldn't share demo.

Comment: @mücahitaltıntaş, sorry we can't use official sample to reproduce this issue.